Multi-Framework Targeting for NuGet Packages
Background - My Build Scripting
I would like to use the dotnet CLI to create a nuget package that can target the following frameworks: net462, net48, net8.0. My library has no dependencies (i.e. it doesn't require any other NuGet packages or projects).
I have written a powershell build script that builds my library such that three DLLs are created.  The relevant part of the build script is included below:
dotnet build TestCI.sln -c "net462" -f "net462" -p:Platform=x64 -p:Version=$($MAJOR_MINOR_PATCH) --no-restore --disable-build-servers
dotnet build TestCI.sln -c "net48"  -f "net48"  -p:Platform=x64 -p:Version=$($MAJOR_MINOR_PATCH) --no-restore --disable-build-servers
dotnet build TestCI.sln -c "net8.0" -f "net8.0" -p:Platform=x64 -p:Version=$($MAJOR_MINOR_PATCH) --no-restore --disable-build-servers

This results in the following folder structure:
bin
|-- net8.0-x64
|-- |-- TestCI.dll
|-- net48-x64
|-- |-- TestCI.dll
|-- net462-x64
|-- |-- TestCI.dll

When decompiled with DotPeek, I can see that each DLL contains:

The information from my .csproj that I would like/expect to see
The proper target framework versions and runtime identifiers

So far, so good.
The Goal - A NuGet Package for Multiple Framework Targets
I would like to package these three DLLs into a single nuget package that can be deployed to net462, net48, and net8.0 runtimes, using only my SDK-style .csproj file and the CLI.
The Problem - Versioning Upon Packaging
My long-term goal is to automate the building and packaging of this library (and others) using GitHub actions - hence the scripting. However, ehcin I run the following dotnet pack command:
dotnet pack TestCI\TestCI.csproj -p:PackageVersion=$($MAJOR_MINOR_PATCH) --no-restore --no-build

The resulting NuGet package contains DLLs that all specify net8.0 as the target framework.  The f
TestCI.nupkg
|-- lib
|-- |-- net462
|-- |-- |-- TestCI.dll
|-- |-- net48
|-- |-- |-- TestCI.dll
|-- |-- net8.0
|-- |-- |-- TestCI.dll

However when inspecting each DLL, they all contain the following line, regardless of the lib subdirecotry:
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET 8.0")]

I.e. there doesn't appear to be a difference between the DLLs packged despite the fact that I know that each DLL was built to a different target framework, and have confirmed this on each DLL in the bin directory.
So Far, I've Tried...
So far, I've tried several variations of the dotnet pack command, even including a rudimentary nuspec file:
dotnet pack TestCI\TestCI.csproj -p:PackageVersion=$($MAJOR_MINOR_PATCH) -p:NuspecFile=.nuspec --no-restore --no-build

(see this post on multi-targeted nuget packages)
This works, however I don't like this soltuion for the following reasons:

The package version isn't properly applied to this package (results in 0.0.0), and I require the ability to control versioning information for CICD purposes.
I would prefer to keep everything contained in my SDK-style .csproj file to keep my repository cleaner and simpler.

I've also ensured that my .csproj file contains the following element:
<TargetFrameworks>net462;net48;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>    

The Asks

Am I misunderstanding how .NET works? Am I needlessly complicating my workflow?
Has anyone encountered a similar situation?
Do I need to use a .nuspec file?
Is it possible to achive what I've described with only a SDK .csproj file and the CLI?

Edits
[2024-07-26]

I am using JetBrains DotPeek to inspect the NuGet package
The csproj file I am using is included below:

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <RootNamespace>TestCI</RootNamespace>
        <Company>XYZ</Company>
        <Copyright>XYZ (c) 2024</Copyright>
        <Version>0.0.1</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net462;net48;net8.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>        
        <Configurations>net48;net462;net8.0-windows</Configurations>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProductName>$(RootNamesapce)</ProductName>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <IsTestProject>False</IsTestProject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageID>$(RootNamespace)</PackageID>
        <PackageVersion>$(Version)</PackageVersion>
        <IsPackable>True</IsPackable>
        <IncludeBuildOutput>True</IncludeBuildOutput>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>False</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <PackageOutputPath>..\nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
        <PackageDescription>XYZ</PackageDescription>
        <RepositoryUrl>XYZ</RepositoryUrl>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
        <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
        <OutDir>bin\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)</OutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>True</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
        <AssemblyName>$(RootNamespace)</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyVersion>$(Version).0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>$(Version).0</FileVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove=".github\**" />
      <EmbeddedResource Remove=".github\**" />
      <None Remove=".github\**" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>



Could you post the csproj file you're using? 2. What are you using to check the target framework of the different dlls in the package?


Added the csproj to the question.  I am using JetBrains DotPeek to inspect the package!

Solution
After several months of research, trial, and error, I was able to find a solution to this problem.  The key was to remove the following elements:
<Configurations>net48;net462;net8.0-windows</Configurations>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
<OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)\</OutputPath>
<OutDir>bin\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)</OutDir>

Removing these elements allows dotnet build to create binaries for each of the target frameworks and allowed dotnet pack to correctly package the DLLs for general consumption.
Details
<Configurations> was unecessary and caused problems.  The MSBuuild defaults, Debug and Release, work best.
<PlatformTarget> proved unecessary.
<OutputPath> changes where the binaries are placed.  Removing this allowed MSBuild to operate using its default folder structure, which solved the build concurrency issues.
<OutDir> caused similar issues to those caused by <OutputPath>. Both proved unecessary when simply using the MSBuild defaults.
Conclusion
The biggest lesson learned here has been that less is more.  MSBuild and the dotnet CLI are good tools.  Stay out of the way and let them cook!
